# Как прочитать 64 битное значение?

Tags: c++, fstream

Мне надо поместить информацию об ELF в структуру заголовка, при этом поля труктуры являются 64 битными значениями. Когда я пробую их прочитать обычным способом, то полчаю 0 во всех полях. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу заставить код представленный ниже работать правильно?

1. hexdump файла из которого надо прочитать ELF байты

   ```
   00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
   00000010  01 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.............|
   00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
   00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  00 00 40 00 05 00 02 00  |....@.....@.....|
   00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   *
   00000080  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000000a0  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000000b0  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000000c0  07 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  90 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000000e0  21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |!...............|
   000000f0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000100  11 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000120  60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |`...............|
   00000130  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000140  19 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  20 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........ .......|
   00000160  0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000170  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000180  b8 3c 00 00 00 bf 00 00  00 00 0f 05 00 00 00 00  |.<..............|
   00000190  00 2e 74 65 78 74 00 2e  73 68 73 74 72 74 61 62  |..text..shstrtab|
   000001a0  00 2e 73 79 6d 74 61 62  00 2e 73 74 72 74 61 62  |..symtab..strtab|
   000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   *
   000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 04 00 f1 ff  |................|
   000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   000001f0  00 00 00 00 03 00 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 10 00 01 00  |................|
   00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
   00000220  00 65 78 31 2e 73 00 5f  73 74 61 72 74 00 00 00  |.ex1.s._start...|
   ```
2. Исходный код для чтения ELF в структуру

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <stdint.h>

   /* Type for a 16-bit quantity.  */
   typedef uint16_t Elf64_Half;

   /* Types for signed and unsigned 32-bit quantities.  */
   typedef uint32_t Elf64_Word;

   /* Type of addresses.  */
   typedef uint64_t Elf64_Addr;

   /* Type of file offsets.  */
   typedef uint64_t Elf64_Off;

   /* The ELF file header.  This appears at the start of every ELF file.  */

   #define EI_NIDENT (16)

   typedef struct
   {
     unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT]; /* Magic number and other info */
     Elf64_Half      e_type;                   /* Object file type */
     Elf64_Half      e_machine;              /* Architecture */
     Elf64_Word      e_version;            /* Object file version */
     Elf64_Addr      e_entry;            /* Entry point virtual address */
     Elf64_Off     e_phoff;              /* Program header table file offset */
     Elf64_Off     e_shoff;              /* Section header table file offset */
     Elf64_Word      e_flags;            /* Processor-specific flags */
     Elf64_Half    e_ehsize;             /* ELF header size in bytes */
     Elf64_Half    e_phentsize;            /* Program header table entry size */
     Elf64_Half    e_phnum;                /* Program header table entry count */
     Elf64_Half      e_shentsize;          /* Section header table entry size */
     Elf64_Half    e_shnum;                /* Section header table entry count */
     Elf64_Half      e_shstrndx;           /* Section header string table index */
   } Elf64_Ehdr;

   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
   {
       Elf64_Ehdr ehdr = {};

       std::ifstream ifs;

       ifs.open("ex1.o", std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);

       for (int i = 0; i < EI_NIDENT; i++)
       {
         ifs >> ehdr.e_ident[i];
       }

       ifs >> ehdr.e_type;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_machine;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_version;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_entry;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_phoff;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_shoff;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_flags;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_ehsize;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_phentsize;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_phnum;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_shentsize;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_shnum;
       ifs >> ehdr.e_shstrndx;

       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Результат:
   Все поля, кроме e_ident содержат 0

Comment: `ifs >>` это для чтения текста, для чтения бинарных данных следует вызывать `read`.

Comment: @VTT Подскажи пожалуйста, как прочитать 64 битное число с помощью read? Ведь он принимает (char *).

Comment: Придется делать `reinterpret_cast`. Кроме того, этот метод позволяет прочитать всю структуру сразу, вместо чтения по одному полю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо всего этого чтения каждого поля по очереди одно чтение

```
ifs.read((char*)&ehdr,sizeof(ehdr))
```

благо у вас явный POD (plain old data, простые старые данные в стиле С).

Забавно - те, у кого структуры не POD - пытаются писать-читать куском в память, а те, у кого чистый POD - напротив, начинают ненужное (да и неверное к тому же) чтение полями...

Comment: Левой скобки не хватает. И C-style кастование тут не к месту.

Comment: Чтение отдельными полями используют те, кто не хочет убирать padding-и заранее неизвестной длины, добавляемые компилятором внутрь структур для выравнивания полей.

Comment: @Arhad Вообще-то куда логичнее указать необходимое выравнивание, чем читать/писать отдельными полями...